# How to reduce computational time in DDE simulation on Matlab

Tags: matlab, simulation, dde

I need to simulate a network of  nodes. The weights of the edges are being given in a matrix . Due to the non-zero distances between the nodes, we consider time-delays, which are computed given the distances and an arbitrary velocity. The delay values have already been calculated. Given that $A$ is symmetric, for a $n$ by $n$ matrix, we have $m=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$  different time-delays.

```
load('A.mat'); % A is a symmetric matrix of dimensions n by n
load('tau.mat'); % tau is the delay array vector with n(n-1)/2 components
tf = 10;
sol = dde23(@(t,y,z)(dde(t,y,z,A)),tau,@(t)(history(t,A)),[0 tf]);
t = linspace(0,tf,200);
y = deval(sol,t);
figure
plot(t,y)
```

The network needs to be expressed in its analytic form as a dynamical system:

$\dot{x}=A_{0}x+A_{1}x(t-\tau_{1})+...+A_{m}x(t-\tau_{m})$

, where $A_{0}$ is the diagonal matrix of the initial $A$ matrix, where it has been considered that since the distance between a node and itself is zero, there is no delay.
In the absence of a way to initialize $m$ different matrices of $n$ by $n$, i created a $P$ matrix as below. Each symmetric pair of $A$ matrix would be put in its respective place of $P$ and multiplied with the respective delay.

```
function dydt = dde(t,y,yd,A)
 n = length(A);
 A0 = diag(diag(A));
 m = n*(n-1)/2;
 P = zeros(n,n*m);
 k = 0;
 for i = 1:n
     for j = 1:n
         if j>i
             P(i,j+n*k) = A(i,j);
             P(j,i+n*k) = A(i,j);
             k = k+1;
         end
     end
 end
dydt = A0*y;
for c = 0:m-1 
    dydt = dydt + P(:,n*c+1:(c+1)*n)*yd(:,c+1);
end
end
function y = history(t,A)
y = rand(length(A),1);
end
```

If the code is technically correct, it is not efficient, since the time it does to produce results increase exponentially even for small number of nodes. For instance, for a network of 7 nodes it takes 2.1 seconds, for 8 nodes 7.6 seconds, for 9 nodes 30 seconds and for 10 nodes almost 121 seconds. This makes its use prohibitive for large networks.

**Does this exponentially increasing computational cost make sense?**

**Is there anything to do to decrease the time of computation?**

Comment: The construction of the large, almost zero matrix $P$ is a significant overhead. We already [had that discussion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4062506/solving-dde-in-matlab-using-matrix-form). It is also possible that with increasing complexity of the model the system becomes more stiff, requiring smaller step sizes. So eliminating $P$ will reduce the base number of function evaluation time, but not the dynamic of the run times.

Comment: So, if I get you correctly, I need to find an alternative way of creating the additional matrices. However, i am not certain if Matlab gives such an opportunity. Does that mean that I should quit trying this with Matlab and try another programming language that might allow initialization of an arbitrary number of matrices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make my comments more explicit:

Try with the following code for the DDE function that eliminates `P`

```
function dydt = dde(t,y,yd,A)
  n = length(A);
  dydt = diag(A).*y;
  k = 0;
  for i = 1:n
    for j = (i+1):n
      dydt(i) += A(i,j)*yd(j,k);
      dydt(j) += A(i,j)*yd(i,k);
      k = k+1;
    end
  end
end
```

This eliminates the $O(n^3)$ matrix-vector multiplications of `P` with `yd`, the effort of filling the non-zero entries of `P` is about the same as directly updating the derivatives vector, the most costly is the explicit double loop.

The suspected result of this change is a general reduction by a factor 2 to 10(?) in the run-time and a somewhat flatter progression of the run-time dependence on `n`.

And yes, for experiments with larger configurations you should use compiled code, in matlab, or using JitCDDE in python (which does a code transformation to C or Fortran and uses the compiled routines) or using the respective julia-lang library.